# Can't get Three.js camera up direction

Tags: three.js, 3d

I need to get the camera up direction and i've tried many ways with no luck, i'm not an expert of quaternions so i'm doubting i did it right.

I've tried:

```
camera.up
camera.up.applyMatrix4(camera.matrixWorld);
new THREE.Vertex3(0,1,0).applyMatrix4(camera.matrixWorld);
camera.up.normalize().applyMatrix4(camera.matrixWorld);
```

after this i create two planes passing by two points of my interest, and add the plane helper to the scene and i can see they are very far from where i was expecting them. (i'm expecting two planes that looks like the top and bottom of the camera frustum).

P.s. the camera is a shadow camera of a directional light so an orthographic camera, and i manipulate the directional light position and target before doing this operation, but i've called `updateMatrixWorld` on the light, on it's target and the camera, on the camera i've called also `updateProjectionMatrix`... still no results

I've made a sandbox to see what i've tried till now, and better visualize what i want to achieve:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/throbbing-cache-j5yse

once i manage to get the green arrow to point to the top of the blue triangle of the camera helper i'm good to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

via trial and errors i've figured out that what gave me the correct result was:

calling

```
directionalLight.shadow.updateMatrices(...)
```

and then

```
new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0).applyQuaternion(directionalLight.shadow.camera.quaternion)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the normal render flow, shadow camera matrices are updated as part of rendering the shadow map (`WebGLShadowMap.render`).

However, if you want the updated matrix values *before* the render, then you'll need to update them manually (you already understand this part).

The shadow camera is a *property* of (not a *child* of) the `DirectionalLight`. As such, it doesn't follow the same rules as other scene objects when it comes to updating its matrices (because it's not really a child of the scene). Instead, you need to call the `shadow` property's `updateMatrices` method (inherited from [`LightShadow.updateMatrices`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/lights/shadows/LightShadow.updateMatrices)).

```
const dl = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1)
dl.shadow.updateMatrices(dl) // <<------------------------ Updates the shadow camera
```

This updates the shadow camera with information from the `DirectionalLight`'s own matrix, and its `target`'s matrix, to properly orient the shadow camera.

Finally, it looks like you're trying to get the "world up" of the camera. Personally, I'd use the convenience function `localToWorld`:

```
let up = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0)
dl.shadow.camera.localToWorld(up) // destructively converts "up" from local-to-camera into world coordinates
```

Comment: giving it a try instantly :D

Comment: dl.shadow.updateMatrices() need a viewportIndex parameter... can i set it to just 0 ?

Comment: i've updated the sandbox to show your direction in dark green also i've called a whole frame render before  getting the values and tried different values of viewportIndex... still no luck

Comment: @L.Trabacchin Sorry, I missed a parameter for `updateMatrices` The docs and the typings file don't match the code... `LightShadow.updateMatrices` requires only a the light for its parameter. Regardless, it's `dl.shadow.updateMatrices(dl)`. Give that a try and see what you get.

Comment: Done! 
Changed 
`let updateFn = this.directionalLight.shadow.updateMatrices as (
      this: THREE.DirectionalLightShadow,
      light: THREE.Light
    ) => void;
    updateFn.call(this.directionalLight.shadow, this.directionalLight);`
But still it doesn't point in the right direction...